# Windows 10 mail app unread folder, add to favourites

Tags: windows-10, email-client, microsoft-outlook-2016

I was trying to create a folder in Windows 10 mail app. On the left-hand side, under sent, delete and more. The folder should consist Unread emails. That what I tried. The name of the folder "Unread" and the emails inside, which was not checked yet or didn't see yet by the user. I believe its something to do with creating a folder and add to favorites. I was able to create a folder but its empty even if I choose from "All" ->"Unread".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was trying to create a folder in Windows 10 mail app. On the
>   left-hand side, under sent, delete and more. The folder should consist
>   Unread emails.  The name of the folder "Unread" and the emails inside, which was not checked yet or didn't see yet by the user. I believe its something to do with creating a folder and add to favorites.

All you have done is create a custom folder called "Unread" just because it is called "Unread" does not mean emails you have not marked as read will appear there. What you describe wouldn't even possible with Outlook, although in Outlook, you can specifically filter by unread emails in a given folder.